# Can't Debug Android Applications

Tags: android, debugging

I've tried to debug the android applications on emulator and than on the device as well but all the time I get the message "Wait for debugger - waiting for the debugger to attach to the process".

I really don't know how to set the environment and the application in order to run the debug.

I Would really appreciate if anyone of you could provide any useful tips.

Comment: It Works For Me (tm).  What's your O/S ?

Comment: How long is "Wait for debugger.." on the screen?  What processor is on your computer?

Comment: Is "Wait for debugger" message in LogCat? Are there messages before and after it?  Does it ever successfully launch any process on emulator or device?

Comment: I found a problem: It was about host configuration:

I had to change the line ::1 localhost
with 127.0.0.1 localhost

Comment: I have the same problem on Mac. Debugger doesn't work. Run works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was in host configuration file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts)

After changing line

```
::1         localhost
```

with

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
```

everything works fine.

Comment: Did you have to reboot after making this change?

Comment: Same problem on Ubuntu. Need restart Android Emulator.

Comment: Had the same issue. After editing the host file to the above the debugger attached fine..

Answer (score 2):

You might want to try just waiting a bit longer.  On my machine the first time I booted it up many moons ago I had the same problem.  It took about 20 or 30 minutes but it finally came up.