# Unable to upload captured image to Server

Tags: android, web-services, capture

I have created the application for capturing the image using Native camera, and i want to `display the captured image in web page(http/ https)`. I have used the following to create the camera application.

[Android: Display Captured image in img tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10510547/android-display-captured-image-in-img-tag)

**Issue**: I can display the captured image in local html file. But unable to load this in html pages in server.

Why i am meeting this issue?

Comment: How are you trying to upload your HTML files and image to the server?

Comment: yes, my web pages are hosted in IIS. but unable to load images to that html files

Comment: Can you confirm that your HTML and Images are being uploaded to the server correctly?

Comment: Images taken from mobile and stored in SDcard, have passed the url from sdcard passed to web page, there not displayed